# Garbage Collector going crazy after a few hours

Tags: java, jboss

Our JBoss 3.2.6 application server is having some performance issues and after turning on the verbose GC logging and analyzing these logs with GCViewer we've noticed that after a while (7 to 35 hours after a server restart) the GC going crazy. It seems that initially the GC is working fine and doing a GC every hour or so but at a certain point it starts going crazy and performing full GC's every minute. As this only happens in our production environment have not been able to try turning off explicit GCs (-XX:-DisableExplicitGC) or modify the RMI GC interval yet but as this happens after a few hours it does not seem to be caused by the know RMI GC issues.

Any ideas?

Update:

I'm not able to post the GCViewer output just yet but it does not seem to be hitting the max heap limitations at all. Before the GC goes crazy it is GC-ing just fine but when the GC goes crazy the heap doesn't get above 2GB (24GB max).
Besides RMI are there any other ways explicit GC can be triggered? (I checked our code and no calls to System.gc() are being made)

Comment: Could it be that the heap incrementally fills up because of some leak somewhere? Then, after some time it is almost full and the GC constantly try to reclaim space without success. How is the heap use evolving over time?

Comment: That is a rather rather old JBoss. Why don't you tell us what libraries are on that JBoss?

Answer (score 3):

Is your heap filling up? Sometimes the VM will get stuck in a 'GC loop' when it can free up just enough memory to prevent a real OutOfMemoryError but not enough to actually keep the application running steadily.

Normally this would trigger an "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded", but there is a certain threshold that must be crossed before this happens (98% CPU time spent on GC off the top of my head).

Have you tried enlarging heap size? Have you inspected your code / used a profiler to detect memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have a memory leak and the if you let the application server continue to run it will eventually crash with an OutOfMemoryException.  You need to use a memory analysis tool - one example would be [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) - and determine what is the source of the problem.  Usually memory leaks are caused by some static or global objects that never release object references that they store.

Good luck!

Update:

Rereading your question it sounds like things are fine and then suddenly you get in this situation where GC is working much harder to reclaim space.  That sounds like there is some specific operation that occurs that consumes (and doesn't release) a large amount of heap.

Perhaps, as @Tim suggests, your heap requirements are just at the threshold of max heap size, but in my experience, you'd need to pretty lucky to hit that exactly.  At any rate some analysis should determine whether it is a leak or you just need to increase the size of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the more likely event of a memory leak in your application, there could be 1-2 other reasons for this.

On a Solaris environment, I've once had such an issue when I allocated almost all of the available 4GB of physical memory to the JVM, leaving only around 200-300MB to the operating system. This lead to the VM process suddenly swapping to the disk whenever the OS had some increased load. The solution was not to exceed 3.2GB. A real corner-case, but maybe it's the same issue as yours?

The reason why this lead to increased GC activity is the fact that heavy swapping slows down the JVM's memory management, which lead to many short-lived objects escaping the survivor space, ending up in the tenured space, which again filled up much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend when this happens **[that you do a stack dump](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html)**.

More often or not I have seen this happen with a thread population explosion.

Anyway look at the stack dump file and see whats running. You could easily setup some cron jobs or monitoring scripts to run `jstack` periodically.

You can also compare the size of the stack dump. If it grows really big you have something thats making lots of threads.

If it doesn't get bigger you can at least see which objects (call stacks) are running.

You can use VisualVM or some fancy JMX crap later if that doesn't work but first start with `jstack` as its easy to use.